# How do I edit a file with a batch program without having the complete path?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch program to rewrite the realmlist.wtf for World of Warcraft and put in the correct realms. I ran into the problem after finishing it that some people had different directories than me(Ex:I had C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\Data\enUS while others had F:\WoW\3.5.5a\data\enUS) I want to find a way to replace this no matter the path before data\enUS. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You should find the install path by looking in the Windows Registry.  As for how to do that from a batch file, see here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregistry.php .  Everybody who has WoW installed should have a registry value in a well-known location that points to the installation's base directory.